# Is TFS and WebDAV usable together?

Tags: web-services, iis, tfs, msdn

The company I work for is a Microsoft partner and we are trying to test out Team Foundation Server 2010 to see if it can be an answer to our "NO VERSION CONTROL" problem.

However, we have several designers, all of which use Dreamweaver. Dreamweaver supports WebDAV and so does IIS.

Is there a way to connect (including checkout and checking in of files) to a Project on a TFS Server (and not just the TFS server itself) using the WebDAV protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS client-server connection is web services, but these are WS-* style operations.

In theory one could use the TFS client code to create one's own WebDAV based API, but there is nothing out of the box.